C# String To URL Execute
Is this a duplicate question ... probably.  There are a million +1 discussions on this topic and I can't get one to work properly.  I have a string.  I want to turn this string into a URL.  I then want to use that URL to navigate to the page in my default browser.  Why is this so difficult?
The closest solution I can find is:
string content = "www.linkedin.com/taylormade-golf-company"
string url = Uri.EscapeDataString(content);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);

This throws the error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannont find the file specified' ".
If I use 'content' in place of 'url' in System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, it takes me to:
"https://www.linkedin.com/taylormade-golf-company?_l=en_US"
How can I simply use a string to navigate to a webpage in code behind?

I think you could run explorer.exe with url string as argument

How can I simply use a string to navigate to a webpage in code behind? - you already did? BUt also, you say "in codebehind" - that's more of a webby term (asp.net) than a desktop app term; you're not trying to do this from a website kind of project are you?

EscapeDataString is the wrong tool to do the job. Its goal is to replace any non-safe characters in a URL with an encoding that is safe to pass the network unchanged.
If the value of content works, then why bother any further?
Anyway, there is an UriBuilder that takes a string in its constructor and then takes a guess when parsing that string, making up things along the way.
string content = "www.linkedin.com/taylormade-golf-company";
var ub = new UriBuilder(content);
Console.WriteLine(ub);

this will output

http://www.linkedin.com:80/taylormade-golf-company

because it made up the scheme and its matching port for you.
If you don't want that, you can set properties on the instance to change those:
ub.Scheme = "https";
ub.Port = 443;

will return

https://www.linkedin.com:443/taylormade-golf-company

but at this point you might as well smack an "https://" in front of your content if it doesn't start with that.
The UriBuilder does also have a Uri property that will return the values the current UriBuilder has a proper Uri type instance instead of a string.
Note that Uri also has a TryCreate but it needs a valid Uri as string and that includes a valid scheme. The value in your content variable is lacking a scheme so TryCreate will return false and you won't get an Uri.

Thank you.  I refactored the code to your specifications, but the System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() doesn't take a UriBuilder.  So, I tried plugging in ub.ToString() and it took me to back to the original "https://www.linkedin.com/taylormade-golf-company?_l=en_US" page.  Is there another method/extension I should be using instead of System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()?

What is the problem? Because the url opens linkedin.com and then handled the 404 response where the JavaScript of linkedin changes the url by adding the locale query parameter _l=en_US. There is no C# code that will change how LinkedIn processes their pages ...
